# REGEXP_EXTRACT in BiqQuery - Extracting whole number or number with decimal

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm currently stuck with the correct REGEXP to extract the number value in BigQuery, where it captures both whole numbers or a number with a decimal point.

For example if the data is stored as follows:

"fee":"1"

This following REGEXP wont work:

select REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, r'"fee":"([0-9]+.[0-9]+)')

This only captures values with a decimal value but if they don't have a decimal value and it's just 1, how do you capture that in REGEXP?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, r'"fee":"([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I knew I was missing the "?" somewhere!!